# How to make it work for p2p?

Tags: java, android, p2p

There are 3 sections, server side, client A for PC and client B for android.
The logic is:
1. When client A and B connect to server, they will be notified another's ip and port.
2. Then A will punch a hole for B and tell the server that it is ready for receiving from B.
3. server will tell B that A is ready.
4. Then B will send message to A.

This is just a simple test, the test environment are:
1. Server has a public IP and port
2. Client A and Client B are in different NAT

The code below is not working. Two peers can't communicate each other. How to make the two peer communicate? I will appreciate every piece of advice.

[Edit]
Thanks, @kha. First time I post here.I will detail the process.
1. No exception from the 3 sections. I got no error.
2. Two clients can connect to server and receive another's ip and port from server.
3. I turned off the firewall for Windows. For android, I don't know how to do this.
4. The two clients just can't communicate, no any other exception.
5. I am new for P2P, so I wanna more help with finding the problem.

Server side code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main {

    static EndPoint endPoint;
    static EndPoint endPoint2;

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DatagramSocket server = new DatagramSocket(5050);
            boolean isSend = false;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("start receiving...");

                EndPoint ep = receiveMessage(server);

                if (endPoint == null) {
                    System.out.println("endPoint initialized");
                    endPoint = ep;
                } else if (endPoint2 == null) {
                    System.out.println("endPoint2 initialized");
                    endPoint2 = ep;
                } else {
                    if (!isSend) {//when A and B all connect to server, they will be notified another's ip and port
                        isSend = true;
                        System.out.println("send to each other");
                        sendEndPointMessage(server, endPoint, endPoint2);
                        sendEndPointMessage(server, endPoint2, endPoint);
                    } else {
                        if ("5".equals(ep.message)) {// client A is ready
                            System.out.println("client A is ready");
                            sendMessage(server, "6", endPoint2);// send B message that A is reay
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void sendEndPointMessage(DatagramSocket server, EndPoint epReceive, EndPoint epContent) {
        try {
            String sendStr = epContent.host + ";" + epContent.port;
            byte[] sendBuf = sendStr.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, epReceive.addr, epReceive.port);
            server.send(sendPacket);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void sendMessage(DatagramSocket server, String msg, EndPoint ep) {
        try {
            byte[] sendBuf = msg.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, ep.addr, ep.port);
            server.send(sendPacket);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static EndPoint receiveMessage(DatagramSocket server) {
        try {
            byte[] recvBuf = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
            server.receive(recvPacket);

            String recvStr = new String(recvPacket.getData(), 0, recvPacket.getLength());
            int port = recvPacket.getPort();
            InetAddress addr = recvPacket.getAddress();

            System.out.println("EndPoint: host:" + recvPacket.getAddress() + ", port:" + port + ", message:" + recvStr);

            EndPoint endPoint = new EndPoint(addr, port, recvStr);
            return endPoint;
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    static class EndPoint {
        InetAddress addr;
        String host;
        int port;
        String message;

        public EndPoint(String host, int port, String message) {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.message = message;

            try {
                addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public EndPoint(InetAddress host, int port, String message) {
            this.host = host.getHostAddress();
            this.port = port;
            this.message = message;

            addr = host;
        }
    }

}
```

Client A for PC:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main {
    public static String serverAddr = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx";
    public static int serverPort = 5050;
    public static String peerIP;
    public static int peerPort;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            final DatagramSocket client = new DatagramSocket();

            sendMessage(client, "1", serverAddr, serverPort);

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("start receiving...");

                String recvStr = receiveMessage(client);

                if ("3".equals(recvStr)) {
                    sendMessage(client, "4", peerIP, peerPort);
                } else {
                    String[] peer = recvStr.split(";");
                    if (peer.length > 1) {// received peer ip and port
                        peerIP = peer[0];
                        peerPort = Integer.parseInt(peer[1]);
                        sendMessage(client, "4", peerIP, peerPort);//punch a hole for client B
                        sendMessage(client, "5", serverAddr, serverPort);//tell server I am ready
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                    sendMessage(client, "4", peerIP, peerPort);//keep punch a hole for client B
                                    sendMessage(client, "5", serverAddr, serverPort);//keep telling server I am ready
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(500);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    } else {
                        if ("7".equals(recvStr)) {// received from client B
                            sendMessage(client, "got from android", peerIP, peerPort);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String receiveMessage(final DatagramSocket client) {
        try {
            byte[] recvBuf = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
            client.receive(recvPacket);
            String recvStr = new String(recvPacket.getData(), 0, recvPacket.getLength());
            String ip = recvPacket.getAddress().getHostAddress();
            int port = recvPacket.getPort();
            System.out.println("received from: host:" + ip + ", port:" + port + ", content:" + recvStr);
            return recvStr;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void sendMessage(final DatagramSocket client, String sendStr, String ip, int port) {
        try {
            System.out.println("send out: host:" + ip + ", port: " + port + ", message:" + sendStr);
            byte[] sendBuf;
            sendBuf = sendStr.getBytes();
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, addr, port);
            client.send(sendPacket);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Client B for Android:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public String serverAddr = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx";
    public int serverPort = 5050;
    public String peerIP;
    public int peerPort;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.connectServer).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        connectServer();
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });
    }

    private void connectServer() {
        try {
            DatagramSocket client = new DatagramSocket();

            sendMessage(client, "2", serverAddr, serverPort);

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("start receiving...");

                String recvStr = receiveMessage(client);

                String[] peer = recvStr.split(";");
                if (peer.length > 1) {// received peer ip and port
                    peerIP = peer[0];
                    peerPort = Integer.parseInt(peer[1]);
                } else {
                    if ("6".equals(recvStr)) {//received from server that client A is ready                     
                        sendMessage(client, "7", peerIP, peerPort); // send message to client A                 
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String receiveMessage(DatagramSocket client) throws IOException {
        try {
            byte[] recvBuf = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
            client.receive(recvPacket);
            String ip = recvPacket.getAddress().getHostAddress();
            int port = recvPacket.getPort();
            String recvStr = new String(recvPacket.getData(), 0, recvPacket.getLength());
            System.out.println("received from: host:" + ip + ", port:" + port + ", content:" + recvStr);
            return recvStr;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void sendMessage(DatagramSocket client, String sendStr, String ip, int port) {
        try {
            System.out.println("send out: host:" + ip + ", port:" + port + ", mesasge:" + sendStr);
            byte[] sendBuf;
            sendBuf = sendStr.getBytes();
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, addr, port);
            client.send(sendPacket);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "not working".

Comment: @kingdamian42 modified, not working means two peers can't communicate each other.

Comment: Which part isn't working? What errors do you get? Can they both connect to your server and obtain each other's IP addresses? Are there any firewall issues? Do you get network exceptions? Have you tried narrowing down the problem and isolating the cause?

Comment: Thanks, @kha First time I post here.I will detail the process.  
1. No exception from the 3 sections. I got no error.  
2. Two clients can connect to server and receive another's ip and port from server.  
3. I turned off the firewall for Windows. For android, I don't know how to do this.  
4. The two clients just can't communicate, no any other exception.  
5. I am new for P2P, so I wanna more help with finding the problem.

Comment: You need to consider this scenario for NATed firewalls. The firewall may create different port mappings for different destinations. More precisely, when Client A sends a packet to server, A's firewall may give it some port(say 51000). When Client A sends packet to Client B after knowing its IP & port, the firewall may use some different port mapping(say 51001). So B might be sending packet to port 51000, as server identifies this & informs B, but firewall at A will accept the packet only if B sends a packet to port 51001. At port 51000, only server could reply back & accepted by A's firewall.

Comment: @RayZhang Can you ping the 2 clients from your PC? Do they respond when you ping them? Are the ports open? There are quite a few things that can go wrong including NAT loopback (as already suggested), firewall issues, blocked ports, bad code, etc.

Comment: @kha, I got one more server for test. And find that from client B with the same port to the server A and server B, there are two different port opened by NAT. My NAT is a Symmetric NAPT. So I think this is the root reason that two peers can't communicate. Thank you for your patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got one more server for test. And find that from client B with the same port to the server A and server B, there are two different ports opened by NAT.
My NAT is a Symmetric NAPT. So I think this is the root reason that two peers can't communicate.
@KunjanThadani, you are right.

Comment: Ok. You can try port prediction. But this would still be a complicated procedure and not sure to work.

Comment: @KunjanThadani, by my test, the ports opened were not in a regular order. So I think the only way is to transfer message through server.

Comment: Ok. Yes, relaying through the server will work. But I suggest you to use tcp instead if it is only about "text messages". It will be more reliable.